# Unable to modify Coffeescript's global variables in a JQuery listener

Tags: coffeescript, global-variables, jquery

Today I was migrating some of my javascript code into coffeescript and got stuck in something really silly but even though I didn't know how to make it work.

I wanted to update the value of a global variable when a click event was triggered, have a look at the code below to see one of my guesses

Here's the code

```
@activeObject = null

# Some other code

$ ->
  $('#header').click ->
    if !headerSelected  
      showMenu '#header-menu', event
    else
      @activeObject = "#header"
      showMenu '#menu-style-header', event
```

Unfortunately even though the click event was triggered the variable was not getting updated.

I came up with a work around. I created a function that set the value of the variable and called it instead of the assignment and this time it worked.

I just wanted to know why I wasn't able to do it the other way. For me it was a simple operation and it seemed silly to define a new function just for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `@` (AKA `this`) inside the click handler isn't the same as it is outside so this:

```
@activeObject = null
```

and this:

```
@activeObject = "#header"
```

are referring to two different `activeObject`s. You should be able to bind everything with `=>` to get the right `this`:

```
$ =>
  $('#header').click =>
    #...
```

or better (IMHO), just refer to `window.activeObject` directly in both places so that it is obvious to everyone that you're referring to a global variable:

```
window.activeObject = null
$ ->
  $('#header').click ->
    if !headerSelected  
      showMenu '#header-menu', event
    else
      window.activeObject = "#header"
      showMenu '#menu-style-header', event
```

Alternatively, you could stop using globals altogether in favor of, perhaps, a data attribute:

```
$ ->
  $('#header').data 'activeObject', null
  $('#header').click ->
    if !headerSelected  
      showMenu '#header-menu', event
    else
      $(@).data 'activeObject', '#header'
      showMenu '#menu-style-header', event
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion is about the usage of `@`, which is basically just a shortcut for this.
If you compile your code and see what CoffeeScript compiler it produces, the confusion becomes  clear

```
this.activeObject = null;

$(function() {
  return $('#header').click(function() {
    if (!headerSelected) {
      return showMenu('#header-menu', event);
    } else {
      this.activeObject = "#header";
      return showMenu('#menu-style-header', event);
    }
  });
});
```

if activeObject is global you whould reference to it

> window.activeObject = null

and

> window.activeObject = "#header";

in both occurences in this code, cause one might be tempted to use it without window in second occurence, but that will cause a new local variable to be implecitly defined.

Generally when starting with CoffeeScript, its usefull to try small snipets like this in
http://coffeescript.org/ on the `Try Now` Tab